# IARC age rating on Windows App store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm about to release a Windows 10 universal app that will depend highly on international distribution.

As of January 6 Microsoft is supposed to have implemented the IARC age rating system:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/06/now-available-single-age-rating-system-to-simplify-app-submissions/

Yet, on my account, as you can see on the image attached, I still have the old rating system where I must provide manually multiple rating certificates.
Does one know why ? And how could I get to the IARC system ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post does say not everyone was getting it right away it was going to be roll out over time.

The IARC rating system will be enabled in some accounts starting today, **and rolled out to all accounts over the next few weeks**. Once your account is enabled with the new workflow:

Comment: I read also it was supposed to be rolled out in January... well I guess you are right my account is not yet activated to support this, I'll see that with msft directly.